# How can I create a single Postgres query which inserts rows sequentially into several tables, some of which depend on each other?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, common-table-expression

**Background**

I'm running Postgres 11 on RDS.

I need to create a single Postgres (SQL) statement that inserts rows into various tables, some of these tables depending on each other such that a certain sequence of inserts is required.

This would be easily done in a Postgres function, but for application reasons I cannot use one here.  It needs to be a single query.

**Setup**

Let's say the basic tables are like this grossly simplified example :

```
create table test_strings_1 (some_string TEXT, some_num NUMERIC);
create table test_strings_2 (some_string TEXT REFERENCES test_strings_1(some_string), some_num NUMERIC);
create table test_strings_3 (some_string TEXT REFERENCES test_strings_2(some_string), some_num NUMERIC);
```

I have seen some excellent examples of non-sequential multiple inserts using CTEs (as [here](https://dev.to/dwd/efficient-insert-multiple-with-postgres-3f06) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203258/conditional-insert-with-a-nested-cte)).  This sort of approach can yield multiple inserts within a single query:

```
WITH foo_1 AS (
          INSERT INTO test_strings_1 (some_string, some_num)
          VALUES ('bar_1',3)
          returning *
    ),
    foo_2 AS (
          INSERT INTO test_strings_2 (some_string, some_num)
          VALUES ('bar_2',4)
          returning *
    )
    
    INSERT INTO test_strings_3 (some_string, some_num)
    SELECT some_string, some_num FROM foo_1
    ;
```

However, as all the `WITH` subqueries are executed in parallel in these CTEs, this approach (at least unmodified) will not reliably work for my case.

How can I create a single Postgres query, not a function or stored procedeure, that will perform multiple inserts in a sequential, one-after-another fashion?

Comment: You need to use the values from `foo_1` in `foo_2`. And you need to use `foo_2` in the final INSERT

Comment: Don't abuse SQL for something it is not made for. Sure, you can write anything in SQL (Turing complete), but I'd write procedural code and conditional processing in client code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks!  That was the missing piece of the puzzle.   (p.s. I realize that this use of SQL is questionable; the guidance is very much appreciated!)